# Source specified in Javascript not showing up in Django template

Tags: javascript, html, django, image

Maybe this is a really dumb question, but I'm learning Javascript and Django and can't figure it out. I've spent a few hours on this and maybe it's a syntax error or something else.

I want to specify the source of an image in javascript and then display the image in Django HTML template. It's not working, even with simple images

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var image = document.getElementById("image").src('https://res.cloudinary.com/.../{{ object.id}}');
        }
```

Here is my image info:

```
<img src="#" id="image" class="mx-auto" width="250px" onerror='this.onerror = null; this.src="https://res.cloudinary.com/.../image.jpg"'/>
```

What am I doing wrong? It's definitely not working - the image is not showing up even when it exists. I either get the default image or no image.

The javascript is in the HTML file and this is what I have at the top of my file:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is the javascript in the `html` file or its own file? When you view source, does the javascript link (with object_id) look right and you can click on it and it brings you to the image you want?

Comment: It's in the HTML file. This code doesn't even work with no object_id and an image link that's fully specified. Nothing comes up to click on if there is no default image specified in the HTML. If I specify a default image i.e. the one error that will show up.

Comment: I think just an issue with your js in the way you set the image url, see my answer

Comment: Try : `var image =$("#image").attr('src','https://res.cloudinary.com/.../{{ object.id}}');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your js:

```js
document.getElementById('image').src = 'https://res.cloudinary.com/.../{{ object.id}}';
```

Comment: I tried this. The broken image picture comes up.

Comment: And if you manually just put a url like this in there? `https://via.placeholder.com/250`

Comment: Can you paste the actual img src that's in your javascript?

Comment: I'm loading the jquery script at the top, not javascript. Maybe that's my problem. How would I add the source in jquery?

Comment: Why not just use vanilla JS? No reason to use jquery for that. But if you must, it'd prob be `$('#image').src('')`